# SPGridview CSS not applying

Tags: sharepoint, spgridview

I have just populated an SPGridview using webpart template in 2010 (NOT USING VISUAL WEBPART).

Following is my CreateChildControls()

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{

    private SPGridView oGrid;
    private DataView oView;

    this.ChromeType = PartChromeType.BorderOnly;
    oView = new DataView(Returnds());

    oGrid = new SPGridView();
    oGrid.DataSource = oView;
    oGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    oGrid = new SPGridView();
    oGrid.DataSource = oView;
    oGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    oGrid.AllowSorting = true;
    oGrid.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(oGrid_Sorting);

    SPMenuField colMenu = new SPMenuField();
    colMenu.ItemStyle.Width = new Unit(200, UnitType.Pixel);
    colMenu.HeaderText = "Title";
    colMenu.TextFields = "Title";
    colMenu.MenuTemplateId = "PresenterListMenu";
    colMenu.NavigateUrlFields = "ID";
    colMenu.NavigateUrlFormat = "do.aspx?p={0}";
    colMenu.TokenNameAndValueFields = "EDIT=ID";
    colMenu.SortExpression = "Title";

    MenuTemplate presenterListMenu = new MenuTemplate();
    presenterListMenu.ID = "PresenterListMenu";
    MenuItemTemplate biogMenu = new MenuItemTemplate("View Goal", "/_layouts/images/Icon_view_Item.png");
    biogMenu.ClientOnClickNavigateUrl = "do.aspx?Id=%EDIT%";

    presenterListMenu.Controls.Add(biogMenu);

    MenuSeparatorTemplate sepMenu = new MenuSeparatorTemplate();
    presenterListMenu.Controls.Add(sepMenu);

    MenuItemTemplate broadcastMenu = new MenuItemTemplate("Edit Goal", "/_layouts/images/ICWM.gif");
    presenterListMenu.Controls.Add(broadcastMenu);

    this.Controls.Add(presenterListMenu);
    oGrid.Columns.Add(colMenu);

    BoundField colProgramme = new BoundField();
    colProgramme.DataField = "Name";
    colProgramme.HeaderText = "Name";
    colProgramme.SortExpression = "Name";
    oGrid.Columns.Add(colProgramme);

    Controls.Add(oGrid);

    oGrid.PageSize = 2;
    oGrid.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found !!";
    oGrid.AllowPaging = true
    oGrid.PagerTemplate = null;
    oGrid.AllowSorting = true;

    oGrid.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(oGrid_PageIndexChanging);
    oGrid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(oGrid_RowDataBound);
    oGrid.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(oGrid_Sorting);

    oGrid.DataBind();
    base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

This populates data but with the default style. I want my custom css to be applied.

Please tell me where i can put my style.css and how can i apply the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your web part, you'll probably want to include your CSS file on the page using:

```
CssRegistration.Register("/path/to/style.css");
```

To apply the styles in your grid, you can set `grid.CssClass`.

See also, [How to use custom CSS with my Sharepoint WebPart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536734/how-to-use-custom-css-with-my-sharepoint-webpart).